# JS loop increment each value by 2

Tags: javascript, loops, operators

Is there a way to increment each result of a loop by 2 each time? So it should increase the values by 2, then 4, then 6...

So if the first result is 2, it should be `2*2=4`
But the second result should be increased by 4: `2*4=8`

This is the loop:

```
function setDatePosition(timelineComponents, min) {
    for (i = 0; i < timelineComponents['timelineDates'].length; i++) { 
        var distance = daydiff(timelineComponents['timelineDates'][0], timelineComponents['timelineDates'][i]),
            distanceNorm = Math.round(distance/timelineComponents['eventsMinLapse']) + 2;
        timelineComponents['timelineEvents'].eq(i).css('left', (distanceNorm*min)+'px');
    }
}
```

At the moment, the first result is left:120px and the second result is left:180px.

I want to achieve:
First result + 20px: 140px

Second result + 40px: 220px

Third result + 60px... And so on

Comment: Post that loop, what you are getting and what you are trying to get, please

Comment: is it increment or multiplication? Where does the 20px come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your 20px coming from min?
If that is the case, you just need to increase min after each iteration. 
`min += 20;`

```
function setDatePosition(timelineComponents, min) {
    for (i = 0; i < timelineComponents['timelineDates'].length; i++) { 
        var distance = daydiff(timelineComponents['timelineDates'][0], timelineComponents['timelineDates'][i]),
            distanceNorm = Math.round(distance/timelineComponents['eventsMinLapse']) + 2;
        timelineComponents['timelineEvents'].eq(i).css('left', (distanceNorm*min)+'px');
        min += 20;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could multiply `distanceNorm` by `i+1` at each iteration:

```
function setDatePosition(timelineComponents, min) {
    for (i = 0; i < timelineComponents['timelineDates'].length; i++) { 
        var distance = daydiff(timelineComponents['timelineDates'][0], timelineComponents['timelineDates'][i]),
            distanceNorm = Math.round(distance/timelineComponents['eventsMinLapse']) + 2;
        timelineComponents['timelineEvents'].eq(i).css('left', (distanceNorm*min*i+1)+'px');
    }
}
```